# How to fix ''Cannot return a void result" Java sort

Tags: java, sorting

When i try to sort a LinkedList with sort, and I run a test I recive the nexte error:
Unresolved compilation problem:
    Cannot return a void result

I have a function that recursive list files in directories and subdirectories. And then return a LinkedList of files. I try to do a sort operation before the return. But I get cannot return a void result.
The List have Files before doing the sort.

```
public LinkedList<File> recursiveFiles(){
LinkedList<File> resultado = new LinkedList<File>();
//Insert Files on resultado
...
Comparator<File> sorter = new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File first, File second) {
                return first.compareTo(second);
            }
        };
        return resultado.sort(sorter);
```

I expect to sort the LinkedList but i get a Compilation problem: Cannot return a void result.

Comment: The return type of `sort()` void.  You have to sort the list, then return the list separately.  Use two statements to do this.  `resultado.sort(sorter);  return resultado;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`List.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) has `void` as return value, because it sorts the list you are calling `sort()` on.

So just call `sort()` and return the list after that:

```
public LinkedList<File> recursiveFiles(){
    // ...
    resultado.sort(sorter);
    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort` sorts the list **in place** and doesn't return anything (i.e., returns `void`). If want to return the list you'll have to do from a separate statement:

```
resultado.sort(sortrt);
return resultado;
```